# Как правильно добавить item в string array android?

Tags: android, массивы

Есть массив:

```
<string-array name="basic_status_list">
       .....
    </string-array>
```

в нем 19 записей, и я хочу записать сюда еще одну запись. На ум приходит два варианта, один из которых я уже попробовал:

```
resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list)[resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list).size+1] = filterModel_notepad.str!!
```

и такой вариант дает ошибку:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=20
```

есть второй вариант - делать создавать переменную которая равна старому массиву, добавлять к этой переменной один item и дальше записывать новый массив в ресурсы. Но мне почему-то кажется что это не очень правильное решение. Как правильно поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: в хардкорные ресурсы нельзя дописать в рантайме ни при каких условиях. могу предложить [такой вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032104/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-item-%d0%b2-string-array-android#comment1757788_1032108)

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, чего вы хотите добиться. Непосредственно в ресурсах вы не сможете изменить элементы массива или добавить новые, они по задумке своей не меняются никак после сборки apk, так что первый вариант не подойдет ни при каких танцах с бубнами. Второй очень даже реалезуем, но тогда 20ый элемент надо добавлять каждый раз при запуске, ведь в ресурсах после закрытия программы так и останется 19.

Если это какие-то фиксированные данные, которые меняются только с обновлением программы(пример: airbnb и типы жилья: гостиница, хостел, отдельная квартира и т.п.), то их имеет смысл "зашивать" в ресурсы, делая доступными, например, их локализацию средствами андроида. Если же это какие-то "оперативные" данные, которые могут прилетать с сервера или вводится пользователем, то хранить их нужно в базе данных, например

Comment: суть в том что эти данные частично фиксированны, и летят с сервера в основном, и поэтому я их забил в ресурсы, но иногда прилетать может больше чем в ресурсах и соответственно при дальнейшей работе нужно это учитывать

Comment: Не очень понял. Так это все таки фиксированный набор или нет? Что он из себя представляет? Типы обрабатываемых объектов или сами объекты? Впрочем, если в некоторых случаях прилетает с сервера что-то, чего может не оказаться в ресурсах, то это уже не фиксированные данные, и лучше их в ресурсах не держать

Comment: получается что данные не фиксированные, но как-то нужно придумать так чтобы часть из них все-таки держалась в ресурсах, так как там есть переводы у фиксированной части)) дилемма однако :)

Comment: Если дело обстоит так, то я бы отдал локализацию на сторону сервера: в запросе указываем клиентскую локаль, и сервер отдает данные уже с нужным переводом, если он есть, или на языке по умолчанию, если его нет. Что это все таки такое? Может зная предметную область смогу предложить что-то поинтереснее

Comment: мда, случай интересный... Можете попробовать совместить два варианта. Ставите жесткое ограничение: если id статуса <19 - берем строку из ресурсов, если нет, то запрашиваем текст для этого id у сервера отдельным запросом. Ну, и кэш под это дело надо оптимизировать, увеличение числа запросов вдвое на пустом месте явно не то, за что коллеги погладят по шевелюре =)

Comment: была идея как-то работать внутри приложения, то есть если пришедший список статусов больше чем тот который есть по-умолчанию, то что-то другое делать, а то на меня уже странно поглядывают коллеги после моих предложений по оптимизации запросов))

Comment: я бы использовал не хардкорные ресурсы и невероятные костыли, а хранил в динамически меняющемся хранилище, как SharedPreferences или любой тип записи (бд, файл, json ...) в зависимости от всего проекта и что в нем используется. По умолчанию в этом хранилище уже есть какой то дефолтный набор, который можно дописать/удалить/изменить

Comment: SharedPreferences позволяет хранить Set из String, что хорошо подходит под задачу. в парах сета id строки и заполненные по умолчанию локализированные строки из ресурсов, так же можно дописывать свои строки в рантайме и сохранить этот сет назад в преференсы